# How to import large csv file into mysql in rails application?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

I'm implementing import csv data into mysql in rails application. I have use **CSV.parse** to read line by line in csv file and import into database. This way works well.

---

But, when I deploy to Heroku server, timeout for each request is 30 seconds. If import csv file more than 30 seconds. Heroku server has error: **request timeout - H12**. Does anyone help me find out the best way to import large csv file? Now, I only import small csv include 70 users. I want import large csv include 500 - 1000 users. Here is the code:

**Import controller:**

```
CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, :headers => true) do |row|
  i = i + 1

  if i == 1
    @company = Company.find_or_create_by!(name: row[0])       
  end

  @users = User.find_by(email: row[1])

  if @users
    if @company.id == @users.employee.company_id
      render :status=> 401, :json => {:message=> "Error"}
      return
    else
      render :status=> 401, :json => {:message=> "Error"}
      return
    end
  else
    # User
    # # Generate password
    password = row[2]
    user = User.new(email: row[1])
    user.password = password.downcase
    user.normal_password = password.downcase
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save!

    obj = {
      'small'   => 'https://' + ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'] + '.s3.amazonaws.com/images/' + 'default-profile-pic_30x30.png',
      'medium'  => 'https://' + ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'] + '.s3.amazonaws.com/images/' + 'default-profile-pic_40x40.png'
    }

    employee = Employee.new(user_id: user.id)
    employee.update_attributes(name: row[3], job_title: row[5], gender: row[9], job_location: row[10], group_name: row[11], is_admin: to_bool(row[13]), 
                is_manager: to_bool(row[14]), is_reviewee: to_bool(row[6]), admin_target: row[7], admin_view_target: row[12], department: row[8], 
                company_id: @company.id, avatar: obj.to_json)
    employee.save!

  end
end
```

I has try use gems 'activerecord-import' or 'fastercsv' but 'activerecord-import' not work, 'fastercsv' not work for ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in a controller seems a bit much to me, especially since it's blocking. Have you given any thought to throwing it in a background job?

If I were you I'd:

1. Upload the file
2. Parse it in the background as a rake task

Also, have a look at: https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Comment: I still try rake task command, but the client want to import from UI :-s.

Comment: Sorry, The clients want import users from UI controller, they don't know background jobs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these lines

```
if i == 1
  @company = Company.find_or_create_by!(name: row[0])       
end

@users = User.find_by(email: row[1])
```

takes a lot of computation cycle in your 30 seconds timeframe.

I would suggest to convert your routine into Heroku background process by using **resque** or **delayed_job**, or split the routine into **n** requests, if we cannot somewhat optimize the code above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I cannot optimize code above. Logic in project very complex. But, you can explain for me "convert your routine into Heroku background process, or split the routine into n requests".

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I referred gems such as resque and delayed_job when saying Heroku background process.

Comment: As for 'split the routine into n requests', I meant to read and save just one (or any number of that fits within 30 seconds) user inside a controller, instead parsing them all at once. However from your additional info, processing them as background process seems easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you. Because the clients of me want import users from a UI controller. I just think idea, call a background job( rake task command ) inside a controller???

Comment: You can call the background job from a controller, however the implementation is not limited to rake task. One of advantages of of implementing the BG job using gems above is that you can even monitor / recover stalling jobs. See here for the idea https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque

Answer (score 0):

Process your CSV in the background, using products such as `delayed_job`, `sidekiq`, `resque`. If it fits your usecase, you can even do this using `guard` or `cron`.

Comment: I can run rake task background jobs from Import controller, right?

Comment: `Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke(args)`. But I do not recommend this. A rake task should be invoked from outside the controller - `cron` or `guard`. You can of course do `system("rake ...")` or backticks or `%x[ ]`